# CATransform3D depth on edge of view that is rotated

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, 3d, core-animation

I have a UIImageView which gets rotated.  When it rotates to the point where it is 90° to the user, it is obvious that the view doesn't have any depth to it. Like looking at a piece of paper at 90°.

I am using:

```
// Rotate

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2 = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2.m34 = 1.0 / -400;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2 = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform2, M_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

How could I add some depth to my view so that when it hits 90° it has an edge more like a 3D object rather than a flat view?

Comment: +1 Great question. I've always wondered how Apple does this when flipping to the iBooks Store in iBooks.

Comment: Yeah, I saw a recreation of that effect, but it was horrible, the perspective was very off.

Comment: Right off the top of my head, this may require two layers. The side layer would begin at 90° transform and animate to 0° or 180° while the face on layer is doing the exact opposite at the same rate. Couple that transformation with a translation along the x axis and it may be convincing.

Comment: That really doesn't sound foolproof. There must be a way to extrude a layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a 3D layer tree in CA by positioning them in 3D space, with one layer per side. So, a 3D rotating cube would have 6 layers; one for each face.

If you make all those layers children of a CATransformLayer (T), you can apply a single transform to T, to, for example, rotate the entire structure in 3D space.

There is no way to "extrude" a CALayer.